# Javascript `defer` doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script defer src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script defer>
// This function is supposed to run when the DOM is ready.
$(function() {

});
</script>
</head>
```

It works if I remove the `defer`'s, but if I leave them in, or just the jquery one I get an error about how $ is undefined. Maybe I'm being an idiot but everything I've read about `defer` says it should load all the scripts and then run them when the document has been parsed.

This is with a recent Firefox.

Comment: The `defer` attribute doesn't work for inline script blocks.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan except the `$` won't work if jQuery loading is deferred.

Comment: Even without the problems being mentioned, I'd wouldn't expect `defer` to guarantee script execution *order* anyway.

Comment: @Quentin, my understanding is that `[async]` ignores execution order, while `[defer]` guarantees it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-defer):

> The `async` and `defer` attributes are boolean attributes that indicate
>   how the script should be executed. The `defer` and `async` attributes must
>   not be specified if the `src` attribute is not present.

Then, only jQuery is deferred, but not the inline script. Therefore, it attempts to use `$` before it is defined, so it throws.